# Error when trying to use parfor (parallel for loop) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, parallel-processing

I am dealing with a very huge matrix and so wanted to use parallel computing in MATLAB to run in clusters. Here I have created a sparse matrix using:

```
Ad = sparse(length(con)*length(uni_core), length(con)*length(uni_core));
```

I have a written function `adj` using which I can fill the matrix `Ad`.
Every time the loop runs, from the function `adj` I get a square symmetric matrix which is to be assigned to the `Ad` from `3682*(i-1)+1` to `3682 *(i-1)+3682` in the first index and similarly in the second index. This is shown here:

```
parfor i = 1:length(con)
  Ad((3682*(i-1))+1:((3682*(i-1))+3682), ...
     (3682*(i-1))+1:((3682*(i-1))+3682)) = adj(a, b, uni_core);
end
```

In a normal for loop it is running without any problem. But in `parfor` in parallel computing I am getting an error that there is a problem in using the sliced arrays with `parfor`.

Answer (score 5):

Outputs from PARFOR loops must either be reduction variables (e.g. calculating a summation) or "sliced". See [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brdqtjj-1.html) in the doc for more.

In your case, you're trying to form a "sliced" output, but your indexing expression is too complicated for PARFOR. In a PARFOR, a sliced output must be indexed by: the loop variable for one subscript, and by some constant expression for the other subscripts. The constant expression must be either `:`, `end` or a literal scalar. The following example shows several sliced outputs:

```
x3 = zeros(4, 10, 3);
parfor ii = 1:10
    x1(ii) = rand;
    x2(ii,:) = rand(1,10);
    x3(:,ii,end) = rand(4,1);
    x4{ii} = rand(ii);
end
```

In your case, your indexing expression into Ad is too complicated for PARFOR to handle. Probably the simplest thing you can do is return the calculations as a cell array, and then inject them into `Ad` on the host side using a regular FOR loop, like so:

```
parfor i = 1:length(con)
   tmpout{i} = ....;
end
for i = 1:length(con)
   Ad(...) = tmpout{i};
end
```

Comment: this seems very useful...Thank you so much .I will be trying this immediately  and will post if any further problems.

Answer (score 4):

[Edric has already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401452/matlab-parallel-computing/5402239#5402239) *why* you're getting an error, but I wanted to make another suggestion for a solution. The matrix `Ad` you are creating is made up of a series of 3682-by-3682 blocks along the main diagonal, with zeroes everywhere else. One solution is to first create your blocks in a [PARFOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/parfor.html) loop, storing them in a cell array. Then you can combine them all into one matrix with a call to the function [BLKDIAG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/blkdiag.html):

```
cellArray = cell(1,length(con));  %# Preallocate the cell array
parfor i = 1:length(con)
  cellArray{i} = sparse(adj(a,b,uni_core));  %# Compute matrices in parallel
end
Ad = blkdiag(cellArray{:});
```

The resulting matrix `Ad` will be sparse because each block was converted to a [sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) before being placed in the cell array.

Comment: the function i have never know that it exists and thank you so much for your reply I ll try this .